# Why is SQL Server suggesting to include predicate columns in the INCLUDE of a new index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, include, non-clustered-index

I have a large query that I'm optimising and it requires an index. I created one that I thought was right, but SQL Server is telling me different. I have extracted the part of the query that needs the index and this sample produces the same index warning:

```
SELECT  CompanyTransaction.Amount
        -- columns from other tables..
FROM Company
    -- JOIN other tables
LEFT JOIN CompanyTransaction
    ON CompanyTransaction.CompanyId = Company.Id
    AND CompanyTransaction.Type = 'SR'
    AND CompanyTransaction.Code = 1000
```

As I'm filtering on CompanyId, Type and Code I presumed they would be the key columns. And as I'm selecting the Amount column I included that in the INCLUDE. The index I put together is the following:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[CompanyTransaction] ([CompanyId],[Type],[Code])
INCLUDE ([Amount])
```

But the index SQL Server is suggesting I create is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[CompanyTransaction] ([Type],[Code])
INCLUDE ([CompanyId], [Amount])
```

This isn't the first time this has happened. Queries in the past have had similar suggestions but I've never looked into it too much. Can anyone provide reasoning for why SQL Server thinks the CompanyId would be better served in the INCLUDE when it's being searched on?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you test the query plans with each index?

Comment: It's probably because it thinks you'll get less rows back by first filtering by Type, Code. For example if you only have one CompanyId, you won't get much selectivity by putting it first.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I did indeed. My index used nested loops whilst the suggested one used a hash match. They're also both equally as fast. Just curiosity more than anything!

Comment: TBH the best index is probably `(Type, Code, CompanyId) INCLUDE (Amount)` this allows a merge as well as a nested loops. A hash join basically means it can't rely on the ordering, which is not ideal. Either way, the suggestion from SQL Server is not reliable, it's just a good indicator that you should rethink the indexing